# PHP Count occurrences of a value of an attribute per item

Tags: json

I have a JSON feed which looks something like this:

```
{
    "Requirement": "Name1",
    "Status": "Passed"
},
{
    "Requirement": "Name1",
    "Status": "Failed"
},
{
    "Requirement": "Name1",
    "Status": "Failed"
},
{
    "Requirement": "Name2",
    "Status": "Passed"
},
{
    "Requirement": "Name2",
    "Status": "Passed"
},
{
    "Requirement": "Name2",
    "Status": "Passed"
},
{
    "Requirement": "Name2",
    "Status": "Passed"
},
{
    "Requirement": "Name2",
    "Status": "Failed"
},
```

What I'm trying to do is to scrape this JSON file and count the occurences of every status per requirement, and store it in associative arrays those would look something like this:

( "Name" => "Name1", "Passed" => 1, "Failed" => 2)
( "Name" => "Name2", "Passed" => 4, "Failed" => 1)

etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
  After 2 cups of coffee I made it:

  foreach($items as $item){

  $requirement = $item["Requirement"];
  $status[$requirement][] = $item["Status"];
  $sumperstatus = array_count_values($status[$requirement]);
  $map[$requirement] = $sumperstatus;
  
  }

  return $map;
```